# Left Join with Multiple Conditions and MAX Value

Tags: oracle, subquery, max, left-join, outer-join

I'm trying to execute a left join where multiple conditions must be met with the inclusion of pulling in the MAX sequence number that meets those conditions.

The left join is on the unique identifier in both tables. Table acaps_history has several rows for each app_id. I need to pull in only one row with the highest seq_number and activity_code of 'XU'. If the code 'XU' doesn't exist for the given app_id, then the case statement above should return 'N' for that row. The code I have currently just isn't working - returning the error "a column may not be outer-joined to a subquery":

```
create table orig_play3 as   
   (select 
    x.*, 
    case when xa.activity_code in 'XU' then 'Y' else 'N' end as cpo_flag

    from 
    dfs_tab_orig_play_x x

    left join cf.acaps_history xa on 
    x.APP_ID = xa.FOC_APPL_ID
    and xa.activity_code in 'XU'
    and xa.seq_number = (select max(seq_number) from cf.acaps_history where FOC_APPL_ID=x.app_id)
    )
```

Comment: Do you only need to check whether `xa` contains a record with a specific activity code for each `x.APP_ID` (or check whether the last record has this activity code)? If so, I'd suggest using a subquery instead of a left join.

Comment: I need to check if `xa` contains the code 'XU' for each `x.app_id`. If it does, pull in only the record with the max sequence number. The max sequence number is relevant when an app_id in `xa` has the code 'XU' listed more than once.

Comment: try smth like `select x.*, (select decode(count(*), 0, 'N', 'Y') from cf.acaps_history xa where x.app_id = xa.foc_appl_id and xa.activity_code = 'XU') from dfs_tab_orig_play_x x`. I can't see where you use some other data from xa, so noneed to outer-join it...

Answer (score 0):

Given your error, it seems that the issue is the last part of your query:

```
and xa.seq_number = (select max(seq_number) from cf.acaps_history where FOC_APPL_ID=x.app_id)
```

This is still operating in the context of the ON clause, so the sub-query to find the max sequence number is the issue.

You should be able to avoid this by moving that sub-query out of the ON clause:

```
LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT FOC_APPL_ID, activity_code, seq_number
          FROM cf.acaps_history
          WHERE activity_code in 'XU'
) xa
ON x.APP_ID = xa.FOC_APPL_ID
WHERE xa.seq_number = (select max(ah.seq_number) from cf.acaps_history ah where ah.FOC_APPL_ID=x.app_id and ah.activity_code in 'XU')
```

Comment: Running that code I get the error: "X"."APP_ID": invalid identifier. Do I need to redefine the driver table (dfs_tab_orig_play_x x) within the sub-query?

Comment: @A.Oli Ah, that makes sense.  I believe you should be able to do that same check in the outer query's where clause though, since the join will have already been executed in that context.  I've updated my answer, try that and let me know if you have better luck.

Comment: @A.Oli Ah, I think it's that the sequence number returned may have been for a record that didn't have `activity_code` set to 'XU'.  I've added that in and tried to better qualify some of the columns in case a conflict of some sort was happening.  If you're still having trouble with those changes though I'd recommend peeling off the WHERE clause or other parts of the query to see what data is getting returned and whether there's something that's accidentally getting filtered out incorrectly.  Now that you're not getting an error it should be a little easier to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

This may be the most inefficient way to execute this query, but it worked... It took like 3 minutes to run (table size is over 600K rows), but again, it returned the results I needed:

```
create table test as (
  select x.*,
  case when xb.activity_code in 'XU' then 'Y' else 'N' end as cpo_flag

  from dfs_tab_orig_play_x x

   left join
       (select 
       xa.FOC_APPL_ID, xa.activity_code, xa.seq_number
       from dfs_tab_orig_play_x x, cf.acaps_history xa
       where x.app_id = xa.FOC_APPL_ID (+)
       and xa.seq_number = (select max(seq_number) from cf.acaps_history where 
       x.app_id=FOC_APPL_ID(+) and activity_code in 'XU')) xb
   on x.app_id = xb.FOC_APPL_ID (+)
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on 12c, I like `OUTER APPLY` for this sort of thing, because it lets you sort the rows for each `app_id` descending by `seq_number` and then just pick the highest one.

```
SELECT
    x.*,
    CASE
            WHEN xa.activity_code IN 'XU' THEN 'Y'
            ELSE 'N'
        END
    AS cpo_flag
FROM
    dfs_tab_orig_play_x x
    OUTER APPLY ( SELECT *
                  FROM   cf.acaps_history xa
                  WHERE  xa.foc_appl_id = x.app_id
                  AND    xa.activity_code = 'XU'
                  ORDER BY xa.seq_number DESC
                  FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY ) xa
```

Note: this logic is a little different from what you posted.  In this version, it will join to the `acaps_history` row having the highest `seq_number` from among 'XU' records for the given `app_id`.  Your version was joining to the row having the highest `seq_number` for the given `app_id`, whether that row was an 'XU' row or not.  I am assuming (with little reason) that that was a bug on your part.  But, if it wasn't, my version won't work as given.